# Unity injection into asp.net web api controllers and filters

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, asp.net-web-api, unity-container

I have WebForms project, and there I have WebApi controller.
How I can inject to controller constructor and to action filter constructor?

I have implemented `IDependencyResolver` and use it in `Global.asax` (`GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver`), but it doesn't help:
on request controller says that there is no default constructor and filter on application start says that it does not contain a constructor that takes 0 arguments.

Moreover, i need singletone injection to action filter.

Thanks.

**UPD**

```
public class ScopeContainer : IDependencyScope
{
    protected readonly IUnityContainer _container;

    public ScopeContainer(IUnityContainer container)
    {
        _container = container;
    }

    public object GetService(Type serviceType)
    {
        return _container.IsRegistered(serviceType) ? _container.Resolve(serviceType) : null;
    }

    public IEnumerable<object> GetServices(Type serviceType)
    {
        return _container.IsRegistered(serviceType) ? _container.ResolveAll(serviceType) : new List<object>();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _container.Dispose();
    }
}

public class IoCContainer : ScopeContainer, IDependencyResolver
{
    public IoCContainer(IUnityContainer container) : base(container)
    {
    }

    public IDependencyScope BeginScope()
    {
        var child = _container.CreateChildContainer();

        return new ScopeContainer(child);
    }
}

public class Global : HttpApplication
{
    void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        RegisterRoutes();
        ConfigureApi(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
    }

    void ConfigureApi(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        var unity = new UnityContainer();

        unity.RegisterInstance<ILogger>(new Logger());
        unity.RegisterType<IRepository, DbRepository>();

        config.DependencyResolver = new IoCContainer(unity);
    }

    private static void RegisterRoutes()
    {
        RouteTable.Routes.MapHttpRoute("ServiceApi", "api/{controller}/{action}");
    }
}
```

Comment: show the implementation of your IDependencyResolver. How do you register the types in the Unity container? Here´s a link how to use IDependencyResolve in WebApi http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/extensibility/using-the-web-api-dependency-resolver

Comment: yes, i read this article and use it

Answer (score 2):

I think this may be the way you are registering your routes.

WebApi routes are registered in the default project examples via the `GlobalConfiguration.Routes` rather than the `RouteTable.Routes` which is used by MVC controllers. If the ApiController is being incorrectly loaded by the MVC routing method it won't find your dependency resolver.

Try modifying your code to this:

```
public class Global : HttpApplication
{
    void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        RegisterRoutes(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
        ConfigureApi(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
    }

    void ConfigureApi(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        var unity = new UnityContainer();

        unity.RegisterInstance<ILogger>(new Logger());
        unity.RegisterType<IRepository, DbRepository>();

        config.DependencyResolver = new IoCContainer(unity);
    } 

    private static void RegisterRoutes(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute("ServiceApi", "api/{controller}/{action}");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issue, I was working on a project trying to help modernize an old web forms project by converting page by page to Web API / Angular and getting the plumbing just right to use Unity was key.

When I was tracing I noticed unity was trying to resolve the controller classes but not the types to inject into their constructors, so I registered my controllers and it all worked. See my example below

Config setup, register controller and dependency

```
void ConfigureApi(HttpConfiguration config)
{
        var container = UnitySingleton.UnityContainer;
        container.RegisterType<IDashboardManager, ExampleStuff>();
        container.RegisterType<DashboardController>(new InjectionConstructor(container.Resolve<IDashboardManager>()));
        config.DependencyResolver = new UnityIoCContainer(container);
}
```

And my controller example:

```
public class DashboardController : ApiController
{
    private readonly IDashboardManager _dashboardManager;

    public DashboardController(IDashboardManager dashboardManager)
    {
        _dashboardManager = dashboardManager;
    }

    public async Task<IEnumerable<string>> Get()
    {
        return await _dashboardManager.GetDatas();
    }
}
```

This is how I got mine working. It was a little different than the article above.